# Reduce flat array to multilevel nested json object array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have following array in JavaScript:

```js
[{
  "province": "Aceh",
  "city": "Banda Aceh",
  "district": "Meuraksa"
}, {
  "province": "Aceh",
  "city": "Banda Aceh",
  "district": "Jaya Baru"
}, {
  "province": "Aceh",
  "city": "Banda Aceh",
  "district": "Banda Raya"
}, {
  "province": "Aceh",
  "city": "Banda Aceh",
  "district": "Baiturrahman"
}, {
  "province": "Aceh",
  "city": "Banda Aceh",
  "district": "Lueng Bata"
}, {
  "province": "Aceh",
  "city": "Banda Aceh",
  "district": "Kuta Alam"
}, {
  "province": "Aceh",
  "city": "Banda Aceh",
  "district": "Kuta Raja"
}, {
  "province": "Aceh",
  "city": "Banda Aceh",
  "district": "Syiah Kuala"
}, {
  "province": "Aceh",
  "city": "Banda Aceh",
  "district": "Ulee Kareng"
}]
```

And I want to convert it to following,

```js
let ddata = [{
  province: "Aceh",
  city: [{
    cityname: "Banda Aceh",
    districts: [
      "Meuraksa",
      "Jaya Baru",
      "Baiturrahman",
      "Lueng Bata",
      "Kuta Alam",
      "Kuta Raja",
      "Syiah Kuala",
      "Ulee Kareng"
    ]
  }]
}];
```

Comment: They all share same province and city, so you can loop over the array and push the districts into new array. Try to implement that, then if you had issue you post those issues here to help you with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the data by creating new provinces and cities, if not present, or pushing new entries.

```js
const reduceDistrictsByProvinceAndCity = (districtData) =>
  districtData.reduce((provinces, item) => {
    let province = provinces.find(p => p.province === item.province);
    if (!province) {
      province = { province: item.province, city: [] }
      provinces.push(province);
    }
    let city = province.city.find(c => c.cityname === item.city);
    if (!city) {
      city = { cityname: item.city, districts: [] }
      province.city.push(city);
    }
    city.districts.push(item.district);
    return provinces;
  }, []);

const districts = [
  { province: "Aceh", city: "Banda Aceh", district: "Meuraksa"     },
  { province: "Aceh", city: "Banda Aceh", district: "Jaya Baru"    },
  { province: "Aceh", city: "Banda Aceh", district: "Banda Raya"   },
  { province: "Aceh", city: "Banda Aceh", district: "Baiturrahman" },
  { province: "Aceh", city: "Banda Aceh", district: "Lueng Bata"   },
  { province: "Aceh", city: "Banda Aceh", district: "Kuta Alam"    },
  { province: "Aceh", city: "Banda Aceh", district: "Kuta Raja"    },
  { province: "Aceh", city: "Banda Aceh", district: "Syiah Kuala"  },
  { province: "Aceh", city: "Banda Aceh", district: "Ulee Kareng"  },
  { province: "Foo" , city: "Bar"       , district: "A"            },
  { province: "Foo" , city: "Bar"       , district: "B"            },
  { province: "Foo" , city: "Baz"       , district: "C"            }
];

const ddata = reduceDistrictsByProvinceAndCity(districts);

console.log(ddata);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```